# FastAPI: Retrieve URL from view name ( route name )

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

Suppose I have following views,

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/hello/')
def hello_world():
    return {"msg": "Hello World"}


@app.get('/hello/{number}/')
def hello_world_number(number: int):
    return {"msg": "Hello World Number", "number": number}
```

I have been using these functions in Flask and Django

- [Flask: **`url_for(...)`**](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/master/api/#flask.url_for)
- [Django: **`reverse(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse)

So, how can I obtain/build the URLs of `hello_world` and `hello_world_number` in a similar way?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

We have got [**`Router.url_path_for(...)`**](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/c566fc6c819f0d565f8cff432351fe009e83d866/starlette/routing.py#L206) method which is located inside the [**starlette**](https://www.starlette.io/) package

#### Method-1: Using `FastAPI` instance

This method is useful when you are able to access the `FastAPI` instance in your current context. (Thanks to [@Yagizcan Degirmenci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13161155/yagizcan-degirmenci))

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/hello/')
def hello_world():
    return {"msg": "Hello World"}


@app.get('/hello/{number}/')
def hello_world_number(number: int):
    return {"msg": "Hello World Number", "number": number}


print(app.url_path_for('hello_world'))
print(app.url_path_for('hello_world_number', number=1))
print(app.url_path_for('hello_world_number', number=2))

# Results

"/hello/"
"/hello/1/"
"/hello/2/"
```

#### Drawback

- If we are using [**`APIRouter`**](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#path-operations-with-apirouter), ***`router.url_path_for('hello_world')`*** may not work since `router` isn't an instance of `FastAPI` class. That is, ***we must have the `FastAPI` instance to resolve the URL***

#### Method-2: `Request` instance

This method is useful when you are able to access the `Request` instance (the incoming request), usually, within a view.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/hello/')
def hello_world():
    return {"msg": "Hello World"}


@app.get('/hello/{number}/')
def hello_world_number(number: int):
    return {"msg": "Hello World Number", "number": number}


@app.get('/')
def named_url_reveres(request: Request):
    return {
        "URL for 'hello_world'": request.url_for("hello_world"),
        "URL for 'hello_world_number' with number '1'": request.url_for("hello_world_number", number=1),
        "URL for 'hello_world_number' with number '2''": request.url_for("hello_world_number", number=2})
    }

# Result Response

{
    "URL for 'hello_world'": "http://0.0.0.0:6022/hello/",
    "URL for 'hello_world_number' with number '1'": "http://0.0.0.0:6022/hello/1/",
    "URL for 'hello_world_number' with number '2''": "http://0.0.0.0:6022/hello/2/"
}
```

#### Drawback

- We must include the `request` parameter in every (or required) view to resolve the URL, which might raise an *ugly* feel to developers.

Comment: Great answer! I'm using Method 2 with ViewModel. I've defined the base ViewModel class to pass the `request.url_for` as an argument called `url_for` (flask nostalgia) and thereby transparently have access to it in my jinja templates (as long as we pass request, which I was already doing)

Answer (score 14):

**Actually you don't need to reinvent the wheel. FastAPI supports this out-of-box** *(Actually Starlette)*, **and it works pretty well.**

```
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/hello/{number}/")
def hello_world_number(number: int):
    return {"msg": "Hello World Number", "number": number}
```

If you have an endpoint like this you can simply use

```
In:  app.url_path_for("hello_world_number", number=3)
In:  app.url_path_for("hello_world_number", number=50)

Out: /hello/3/
Out: /hello/50/
```

In **FastAPI**, **APIRouter** and **FastAPI(APIRoute)** inherits from **Router**(Starlette's) so, if you have an **APIRouter** like this, you can keep using this feature

```
router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/hello")
def hello_world():
    return {"msg": "Hello World"}

In:  router.url_path_for("hello_world")
Out: /hello
```

Comment: What would you suggest as an approach when you have multiple router files, and want to get the `url_path_for` a route in a different file? My `main.py` does a bunch of `app.include_router` to get all the routes.Thanks!

Comment: @Shawn I used `return fastapi.responses.RedirectResponse(url=request.url_for(name='account'), status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)` in my view function based view

Comment: your approach returns path, not URL. `flask.url_for()` returns absolute URL value

Answer (score 3):

url_for exists, but is provided by starlette, the server underpinning FastApi:
https://www.starlette.io/routing/#reverse-url-lookups

Answer (score 1):

If the same function name is defined under multiple APIRouters, `request.url_for` and `router.url_path_for` would return the first matching function name (in the order of include_router).
Here is a way to get the correct url with the tag of APIRouter when there is a function name conflict, if someone needs it:
**Step 1:** put this in your `__init__.py`:

```
def url_of(request: Request, name: str, **path_params: dict):
    from fastapi.routing import APIRoute
    from starlette.routing import NoMatchFound
    tag, tid, fname = None, name.find('.'), name
    if tid > 0:
        tag = name[:tid]
        fname = name[tid + 1:]
    url_no_tag = None
    for route in request.app.router.routes:
        if not isinstance(route, APIRoute):
            continue
        if fname == route.name and (not tag or tag in route.tags):
            try:
                url_path = route.url_path_for(fname, **path_params)
                url_no_tag = url_path.make_absolute_url(base_url=request.base_url)
                if tag:
                    return url_no_tag
            except NoMatchFound:
                pass
    if url_no_tag:
        return url_no_tag
    return request.url_for(name, **path_params)
```

**Step 2:** add a tag for APIRouters:

```py
router = APIRouter(prefix='/user', tags=['user'])
@router.get('/')
def login():
    return 'login page'
```

**Step 3:** retrieve the url in any where:

```py
@router2.get('/test')
def test(request: Request):
    return RedirectResponse(url_of(request, 'user.login') + '?a=1')
```

2021/07/10  rename `url_as` to `url_of`

Comment: it's working fine.but you can only redirectResponse when parent and target method have same route .Eg if test is post method means you can only call a post method instead you can't call the get method using the post method request object.

Comment: This answer aims to solve the problem of building URL from function name proposed by 'jpg'. RedirectResponse is an example of how to use the built URL. RedirectResponse is returned with 307 as the default status code (a new request is initiated in the same way during redirection). If the 'test' needs to be POST and 'login' is GET, we can set the status_code parameter as 302: `RedirectResponse(url_as(request, 'user.login') + '?a=1', status_code=302)`. The `url_as` can also be used in other ways. In fact, I register the `url_as` as a global template method in jinja2 @NAGARAJS

Comment: If the `request` In `request.url_for` is an incoming request instance, you don't need to implement the function `url_of(...)`, because, the `request` object has all the route informations.

Comment: I didn't test the `request.url_for` adequately, `url_for` can indeed get all the urls of the app by the function name. But if the same function name is defined under multiple APIRouters, `url_for` would return the first matching function name (in the order of include_router). `url_of` provides a way to get the correct url with the tag of APIRouter when there is a function name conflict. The answer has been updated. Thanks @JPG

Answer (score 0):

If you need to resolve URLs in template, Starlette (so FastAPI) defines the
`url_for()` function in the default Jinja environment by using the `request`
instance of the context and `url_for` method:

https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/master/starlette/templating.py#L63

To use it in template: `{{ url_for('hello_world_number', number=42) }}`.

Comment: It was not mentioned that `url_for` is exported in the template context.