# How to get full server URL from any endpoint handler in Gin

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm creating an endpoint using Go's Gin web framework. I need full server URL in my handler function. For example, if server is running on `http://localhost:8080` and my endpoint is `/foo` then I need `http://localhost:8080/foo` when my handler is called.

If anyone is familiar with Python's fast API, the `Request` object has a method `url_for(<endpoint_name>)` which has the exact same functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63682957/5353128

In Go, I've tried accessing `context.FullPath()` but that only returns my endpoint `/foo` and not the full URL. Other than this, I can't find appropriate method in docs: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context

So is this possible via `gin.Context` object itself or are there other ways as well? I'm completely new to Go.

Comment: Do you want to get `http://localhost:8080/foo` from gin context or handle path variable like you mentioned in python example?

Comment: @nipuna I want to get that base URL from gin context as that's only available object inside my handler function. I don't want to handle path variables.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`c.Request.Host+c.Request.URL.Path` should work but the scheme has to be determined.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/foo", func(c *gin.Context) {
        fmt.Println("The URL: ", c.Request.Host+c.Request.URL.Path)
    })

    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

You can determine scheme which also you may know already. But you can check as follows:

```
scheme := "http"
if c.Request.TLS != nil {
    scheme = "https"
}
```

If your server is behind the proxy, you can get the scheme by `c.Request.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-Proto")`

Comment: Related: [Why are request.URL.Host and Scheme blank in the development server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899069/why-are-request-url-host-and-scheme-blank-in-the-development-server)

Comment: @blackgreen Yes, I noticed that too basically on development server nothing much available on `Request.URL` except `Path`. That is why I think it's safer to user `Request.Host` for host.

Comment: Thanks. How did you come up with this? Is it documented?

Comment: @Kaushal28 not directly documented, because this depends on the http library, not Gin. See this https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/issues/1233

Comment: @Kaushal28 As blackgreen mentioned, it's not documented directly. But you come to know it by experience specifically if you have it with `net/http` library.

Comment: Might this not be unsafe? It reads the url _from the request_. From its doc string: "To prevent DNS rebinding attacks, server Handlers should validate that the Host header has a value for which the Handler considers itself authoritative." - The _real_ server url might be different, might it not?

Answer (score 2):

You can get `host` part `localhost:8080` from `context.Request.Host` and `path` part `/foo` from `context.Request.URL.String()`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/foo", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.String(http.StatusOK, "bar")
        fmt.Println(c.Request.Host+c.Request.URL.String())
    })
    // Listen and Server in 0.0.0.0:8080
    r.Run(":8080")
}
```

And you can get http protocol version by `context.Request.Proto`, But it will not determine `http or https`. you need to get it from your service specifications.