# How to refresh the current page in Golang after executing a function

Tags: go, simulation, go-gin

I have a small Golang project that uses templates to display tables in a browser, which it retrieves from a remote server that simulates an Economy. The remote server has an API with endpoints to carry out actions for example 'Trade' or 'Produce'.

Effectively, the project is functioning as a front end. I used Go because it had a lower learning curve for me than, say, React or .js based solutions and because it was a way to learn Go by using it for a practical applicatin.

This doesn't seem to be a very common use case (which may mean it's not a good idea) so I haven't been able to find many standard answers to the issues that my project is generating. Maybe there is a community out there that I haven't found yet.

When the remote server has satisfied the request, I want the browser to update whatever table the user is currently looking at, that is, refresh the current page but with modified data. The remote server can update the data, but it doesn't know anything about how this data is being displayed, because I want a complete separation of concerns.

How do I simply refresh this current page? This is something I have been able to do in Django, but can't find the equivalent in Go or gin. For most of the examples I have studied, Gin would generate a GET or POST request which returns the data required for a specific page, related to the request (for example 'display all industries' or 'display one industry'). But I want to display whatever table the user was currently looking at.

I am using gin to handle the table displays but I am not wedded to it.

Comment: should that reload be triggered by the server (e.g: a redirect) ? or by the client (e.g: in the javascript code) ?  what do you have in mind when you say "I have been able to do [this] in Django" ?

Comment: why not use WebSockets implementation ??

Comment: @LeGec the client will trigger the refresh, because it will only ask for the data that it needs to display. The server does not know what is being displayed. As regards Django, I did this a while back so cannot recall the exact procedure from memory (I can look at the code if that would help).

Comment: I could perhaps use websockets but it seems to me there must be a way to do this using either the Go default http methods, or gin-gonic, or both. I would have thought it is quite a common requirement. Basically the client app just tells the server to do something, and continues displaying the same template as before, though (if required) with refreshed data, which it asks for

Comment: @ancientgeek: ok, in that case, this should be added to your javascript code. How is the code for your HTML page served ? for example: is it served directly by your go server ? or is it loaded in some other way, with your go server serving exclusively a json api ?

Comment: @LeGec the code for the HTML page is served directly by the go server, with a call to a handler function taking a gin Context object (let's call this ctx) as parameter. This go hander then calls the ctx.HTML method, handing it a template name and a payload consisting of the data to be displayed. I guess I could just store this template and payload in some more permanent variable eg 'LastUsedTemplate' and 'LastPayload' but this seems pretty janky. I'm wondering if this is a common use case with a standard solution.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I am trying to make an essentially stateless app remember its state from one request to the next.

Comment: quick hack is: add a `<script> ... </script>` tag in your rendered HTML page. If you need to have client side intelligence though, I would recommend to serve a `static/app.js` file sooner rather than later.

Comment: I'd certainly give that a try. Nice tip

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this as follows:

The app maintains a list of logged-in users (which is stored as a map, but anything that yields a User model should do)

Each User is represented by a struct containing a field `lastLoggedIn` which contains the relative URL of the page that user was visiting, at the time of the request to undertake some action or other (such as updating the simulation)

After the action is complete, its handler calls

```
ctx.Redirect(http.StatusFound, lastVisitedPage)
```

where `ctx` is the `*gin.Context` parameter passed into the handler that generates the action

I found the following to be useful sources of information:

https://gin-gonic.com/docs/examples/redirects/

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836237/how-to-get-full-server-url-from-any-endpoint-handler-in-gin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836237/how-to-get-full-server-url-from-any-endpoint-handler-in-gin%5D)

Worth nothing that the second reference says

> If anyone is familiar with Python's fast API, the Request object has a
> method url_for(<endpoint_name>) which has the exact same
> functionality

So maybe other users migrating from Python to Go have experienced similar puzzlement