# FastAPI return image as JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, fastapi

I have an API for random tea photos but would like it to return the photo in JSON as a URL for discord bots and things.  This is what I have so far:

```
def getRandomFile(path):
  """
  Returns a random filename, chosen among the files of the given path.
  """
  files = os.listdir(path)
  index = random.randrange(0, len(files))
  return files[index]



@app.get("/")
async def home():
  return RedirectResponse("/docs")

@app.get("/tea")
def tea():
    x = "teacuppics/{}".format(getRandomFile("teacuppics"))
    return FileResponse(x)
```

How do I swap the reply of images to JSON reply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`static files`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/) directory to serve static files such as images. Include your `teacuppics` folder inside the `static` directory and mount a `StaticFiles()` instance in that directory. You can then use `request.url_for()` function to get the URL of a randomly selected image. Example below:

```
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
  
@app.get('/tea')
def tea(request: Request):
    img = "teacuppics/{}".format(getRandomFile("static/teacuppics"))
    img_url = request.url_for('static', path=img)
    return {'img_url': img_url}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request.url_for` what generate url according to host. (on localhost it will be 127.0.0.1, on hosting it will be [www.your-page.com](http://www.your-page.com)). Argument is name of function. It was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63682956/fastapi-retrieve-url-from-view-name-route-name) as well.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse


app = FastAPI(title='FASTAPI BLANK', version='1')


@app.get("/tea/{img}")
async def tea(img: str) -> FileResponse:
    return FileResponse(img)


@app.get('/json_tea')
async def tea2(request: Request) -> JSONResponse:
    rnd_pic = '11dfdvf.jpg'
    pic_url = request.url_for('tea', img=rnd_pic)
    return JSONResponse(content={'teacuppics': pic_url})
```

Comment: I am trying to get the image URL.  I have managed to get it to respond with the image name but not Image:URL for the random image