# How to navigate through FastAPI routes by clicking on HTML button in Jinja2 Templates?

Tags: python, html, jinja2, fastapi, starlette

I have a FastAPI app with some routes working fine if I move around them manually (i.e., by changing the `/<path>` in the browser's address bar). For example, this is one of them:

```py
@task.get('/tasks', response_model=list[Task], tags=["Tasks"])
def find_all_tasks():
    print("\n[*] Showing all Tasks\n")
    return tasksEntity(conn.local.task.find())
```

My `/<root>` route loads an `index.html` file that displays a button. What I want to do is whenever I click the button to have the above route added to the url (e.g., `http://127.0.0.1/tasks`).

I use `Jinja2Templates` to render data in the HTML from different routes of the API, but I dont know how to move around them from the frontend HTML buttons.

Answer (score 3):

### Backend

Your `/tasks` endpoint (i.e., `find_all_tasks` function) should return a new Jinja2 `TemplateResponse` with the `list` of `tasks`. For instance:

```py
@app.get('/tasks')
def find_all_tasks(request: Request):
    tasks = ['task 1', 'task 2', 'task 3']
    return templates.TemplateResponse("tasks.html", {"request": request, 'tasks': tasks})
```

### Frontend

###### 1. Click on the URL to get to the `tasks` page

In `index.html`, you can use the `url_for()` function to get the URL for an endpoint and allow the user to click on it, for example:

```html
<a href="{{ url_for('find_all_tasks') }}">Click me</a>
```

or

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('find_all_tasks') }}">  
   <button>Click me</button>  
</form>
```

or

```html
<button onclick="location.href='{{ url_for('find_all_tasks') }}';">Click me</button>
```

or

```html
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='{{ url_for('find_all_tasks') }}';" value="Click me"/>
```

Alternatively, you can use relative paths, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71306247/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636404/17865804), passing the name of the route and any required path/query parameters. For example:

```html
<a href="/tasks">Click me</a>
```

If your endpoint contains *path* and/or *query* parameters, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70633588/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71068465/17865804) on how to include those as well.

###### 2. Display `tasks`

In `tasks.html` template, you can loop through and output the `tasks` inside braces, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70996841/17865804) and below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        {% for task in tasks %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ task }}</td><br>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63682956/fastapi-retrieve-url-from-view-name-route-name) you can use `app.url_path_for('find_all_tasks')` to get the url of your route. You can pass this as a parameter to Jinja and then in your temlate you want something like

```html
<form action="{{ find_all_tasks_route }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to all tasks" />
</form>
```

( taken [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-do-i-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link) )

where `find_all_tasks_route` was the parameter you passed to the renderer.