# Python FastApi. Data not displayed when using templates

Tags: python, templates, localhost, fastapi

Just created my first fast api interface. Quite simple. I want to display a list of rows on the page.

python code is:

```
## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Collect data
## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

idb = sqle.db_engine(tg_db_name, data_path)
idb.connect()
rows = idb.ticker_list()
idb.close_db()

## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Main
## ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")

def index(request: Request):
    # print(dir(request))
    # return{"Hello":"DashBoard", "Stocks" : rows}
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request, "Stocks": rows})
```

when not commented, the following line displays the rows information information

```
   return{"Hello":"DashBoard", "Stocks" : rows}
```

[rows displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NTbF.jpg)

when not commented, this one just returns an empty page. Just "Stocks" is displayed at the top.

```
     return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request, "Stocks": rows})
```

[Not displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FLkm.jpg)

here below the index.html template

```
<html>
    <head>
        <tile>Stocks</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
        {% for row in rows %}
            {{ rows.id }}
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

also, row type is <class 'list'>

and it is the retreival of an sqllite query.

```
   mySql = ('''SELECT id_ticker, tx_ticker_symbol, tx_ticker_code, 
               tx_ticker_name, tx_ticker_fullname 
              FROM Ticker''')
    self.cursor.execute(mySql) 
    rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
    
    return rows
```

I would expect the following line to display the rows information.

```
     return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request, "Stocks": rows})
```

Also, I don't understand why rows is return as a list and not a dictionary.

Comment: What do you expect `{% for row in rows %}` to do? You're assigning your rows under the name `Stocks`: `"Stocks": rows` - so you'll have to refer to it by that name: `{% for stock in Stocks %} {{ stock.id }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: thks. I do understand now.

Comment: any reason why i get a list rather than a dictionnary  when using self.cursor.fetchall() ?

Comment: `fetchall` means to fetch _all rows_, so that needs to be a list? A list of rows. If you want the _elements_ of the list to be dictionaries, that support might depend on your library, but for `mysql-connector-python`, you can use `connection.cursor(dictionary=True)` to get a cursor that returns rows as dictionaries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to navigate through FastAPI routes by clicking on HTML button in Jinja2 Templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237542/how-to-navigate-through-fastapi-routes-by-clicking-on-html-button-in-jinja2-temp)

Comment: thks to all ! working quite well so far