# How to speed up JSON response in FastAPI?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, fastapi

I have a FastAPI endpoint like this:

```py
@app.get("/api/triggers")
async def get_triggers(s_id: str = Query(None), trigger_id: str = None, limit: str = None, offset: int = None,
                    session: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    if trigger_id:
        if "," in trigger_id:
            trigger_id = trigger_id.replace(" ", "").split(',')
        else:
            trigger_id = [trigger_id]
        trigger_info = session.query(Trigger).filter(Trigger.id.in_(trigger_id)).offset(offset).limit(limit).all()
        for key in trigger_info:
            del key.geometry_global
        return trigger_info
    if s_id:
        if "," in s_id:
            s_id = s_id.split(',')
        else:
            s_id = [s_id]
        result = session.query(Trigger).options(load_only("id", "geometry_global")).offset(offset).limit(limit). \
            filter(Trigger.s_id_fk.in_(s_id)).all()
    else:
        result = session.query(Trigger).options(load_only("id", "geometry_global")).offset(offset).limit(limit).all()
    return ORJSONResponse(result)
```

How can I speed it up? There are million of rows in the table and json response seems to be very slow. I have added pagination, so that chunks of data can be retrieved by multiple api calls. But Is there any other way by which response can be speed up?

Comment: is the problem related to the `SQL` query?

Comment: If query can be optimized that would be good, but the main issue is that the JSON response is very large, which takes a lot of time to be sent.

Comment: are you sure that the main delay is when sending a response, and not in processing, `json.dumps()` etc?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastAPI is very slow in returning a large amount of JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73564771/fastapi-is-very-slow-in-returning-a-large-amount-of-json-data)

Comment: You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) helpful

Comment: May I ask how exactly are you testing the endpoint? Is it through Swagger UI, or accessing the endpoint directly from the browser, or some other means? If it is either one of the first two, the delay you experience has mostly to do with the browser displaying the data (hence, client side issue), as explained in the first link above. If so, why would you want to display _"millions of rows"_ in a browser, instead of returning them as an `attachment` file that the client could download? Please have a look at all the links provided above, which provide examples and explanation around this topic.

Comment: The api is being called in a react app, where we have a map & all the data needs to be plotted. So it takes some time to plot the data. I have looked at the answers provideed above. I added ORJSONresponse, but it didn't help much. Maybe i need to look at other serialization techniques like protobuf & flatbuffer along with grpc apis instead of rest.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem overview

If you are accessing the endpoint directly from the browser, the delay you may experience has mostly to do with the browser displaying the data, as you mentioned there are **millions of rows** to be returned; hence, this is a client-side issue and not so much a server-side one.

### Suggestions

1. Instead of returning an `ORJSONResponse`, which would result in displaying the data in the browser, you could instead return a custom `Response` and set the `Content-Disposition` response header, using the `attachment` parameter, indicating to the browser that the data should be *downloaded* as a file, instead of *viewed* in the browser. Please have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804), as well as [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804) for more details on returning JSON data and how to speeed up this process. Example:

   ```py
   import orjson
   # ...
   results = session.query(...
   headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="data.json"'}
   return Response(orjson.dumps(results), headers=headers, media_type="application/json")
   ```
2. If you still need to display the results in the browser, I would suggest having a frontend—which could easily be created using Jinja2  templates and HTML, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74237972/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74338314/17865804)—and instead of fetching all the results at once (since there are millions of rows, which would not make any sense to return them all at once anyway), rather fetch a few rows at a time (e.g., 1000 rows) and have a <kbd>Load more</kbd> button on which users can click to fetch more results (or use pagination). Additionally, provide a filter mechanism that would allow users to filter the results as desired, and hence, retrieve only those results they are interested in, resulting in faster query execution and less data to be returned.