# Python FastAPI: How to return a Response with Unicode or non-ASCII characters encoded into JSON or CSV data?

Tags: python, json, csv, character-encoding, fastapi

I try to do a FastAPI that trigger file downloading through the `StreamingResponse()` Class (see [FastAPI page](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse)). It is actually ok for this part.

My problem is that when the file contains accent (e.g é) or another special character, it seems to not encode it well.

For example, when there is a `é`, in a CSV it will be transformed to `Ã©` and in a JSON to `\u00e9`.

My code is something like:

- For JSON

```
# API CONTENT
# ...

return StreamingResponse(io.StringIO(json.dumps(data)), headers={"Content-Disposition": "filename=filename.json")
```

- For CSV

```
# API CONTENT
# ...

return StreamingResponse(io.StringIO(pandas.DataFrame(data).to_csv(index=False)), headers={"Content-Disposition": f"filename=filename.csv"})
```

In order to fix the encoding, I also tried to:

- Add  `media_type="text/csv; charset=utf-8"` in the CSV part but without success.
- Add `"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8"` in the header part but without success too.
- Tried to replace `StreamingResponse` by `Response` .

Do somebody already faced this kind of problem. I want to precise that the content before add it into `StreamingResponse` is well encoded.

Here is a sample of code to test:

````
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
import pandas as pd
import io
import json

app = FastAPI()

data = [
    {"éète": "test", "age": 10},
    {"éète": "test2", "age": 5},
]

@app.get("/download_json")
async def download_json():
    return StreamingResponse(io.StringIO(json.dumps(data)), headers={"Content-Disposition": "filename=data.json"})

@app.get("/download_csv")
async def download_csv():
    return StreamingResponse(io.StringIO(pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(index=False)), headers={"Content-Disposition": "filename=data.csv"})```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's `json` module, by default, converts non-ASCII and Unicode characters into the `\u` escape sequence. To avoid having non-ASCII or Unicode characters converted in that way, when encoding your data into JSON, you could set the `ensure_ascii` flag of `json.dumps()` function to `False`. Similalry, when using Panda's DataFrame [`to_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)or [`to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) functions, you need to make sure to use them with `force_ascii=False` and `encoding='utf-8'` arguments, respectively. (Note that `encoding='utf-8'` is the default encoding for the `to_csv()` function regardless; hence, you might omit manually setting it).

Regarding using `StreamingResponse`, I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804) and all the references included in it, in order to understand whether and when you should use it. In your case, as shown in the example given in your question, is not needed, but you should rather return a custom `Response`, as explained in the linked answer above. More related answers that you might find helpful can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205127/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75760884/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241648/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76122475/17865804). I would also highly suggesting reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804), which would clear things up for you, regarding how FastAPI works inder the hood, when returning dictionary/JSON objects from an endpoint. To use faster JSON encoders than the standard `json` module, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74173023/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73580096/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76206076/17865804).

Finally, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586180/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71643439/17865804), you could define the `Content-Disposition` header, so that the data are either *viewed* in the browser or *downloaded* to the client's device, using either:

```
headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="out.json"'}
```

or

```
headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="out.json"'}
```

Please have a look at the linked answers for more details.

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
import pandas as pd
import json


app = FastAPI()


# Exemple de données avec des caractères spéciaux
data = [
    {"éète": "test", "age": 10},
    {"éète": "test2", "age": 5},
]

    
@app.get("/1")
def get_json():
    headers = {"Content-Disposition": 'inline; filename="out.json"'}
    return Response(
        json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False),
        headers=headers,
        media_type="application/json",
    )


@app.get("/2")
def get_json_from_df():
    headers = {"Content-Disposition": 'inline; filename="out.json"'}
    return Response(
        pd.DataFrame(data).to_json(orient="records", force_ascii=False),
        headers=headers,
        media_type="application/json",
    )


# Note: "text/csv" would force the browser to download the data, regardless
# of specifying `inline` in the `Content-Disposition` header.
# Use `media_type="text/plain"` instead, in order to view the data in the browser.
@app.get("/3")
def get_csv_from_df():
    headers = {"Content-Disposition": 'inline; filename="out.csv"'}
    return Response(
        pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(index=False, encoding="utf-8"),
        headers=headers,
        media_type="text/csv; charset=utf-8",
    )
```

### UPDATE - Downloading CSV file and making Excel automatically displaying UTF-8/UTF-16 data when double-clicking the file

As noted in the example provided above, when calling `/3` endpoint, while the file that gets downloaded is in `utf-8` encoding—one can confirm that by opening the file in Notepad++ and checking the encoding used, as well as finding that all unicode/non-ascii characters are displayed as expected—when, however, double-clicking on the file to open it in Excel, unicode/non-ascii characters, such as `é` and `è` in the example above, are not displayed correctly.

As it turns out, this is a known issue with Excel—have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002256/is-it-possible-to-force-excel-recognize-utf-8-csv-files-automatically), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155097/microsoft-excel-mangles-diacritics-in-csv-files) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1704749/open-utf-8-csv-files-by-double-clicking-in-excel) for more details—and the way to overcome this is to prepend a [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (i.e., `\uFEFF`) at the beginning of the file, which would result in Excel recognising the file as UTF-8 or UTF-16. Depending on the Excel version one is using, they should use the appropriate encoding. In some older versions, one would need to use `utf-16` encoding (or `utf-16-le`), as shown in the example below, while in newer versions `utf-8` might work as well (in which case, one would need to replace `utf-16` with `utf-8` in the example below). Finally, make sure to use `\t` delimiter (i.e., , `sep='\t'`), in order for the data to be displayed in separate columns in the CSV file; otherwise, using `,` or `;` for instance, all data might end up in a single column.

##### Option 1 - Using Pandas DataFrame

```py
@app.get("/3")
def get_csv_from_df():
    headers = {"Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="out.csv"'}
    return Response(
        (u'\uFEFF' + pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv(index=False, sep='\t', encoding="utf-16")).encode('utf-16'),
        headers=headers,
        media_type="text/csv; charset=utf-16",
    )
```

##### Option 2 - Using Python's built-in `csv` module

Alternatively, one could use Python's built-in `csv` module to convert the dictionary or list of dictionaries into csv data and have them sent to the client. To avoid, however, saving the data to a file on the disk, one could use Python's `NamedTemporaryFile`, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70665801/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653605/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73324461/17865804), which would be much faster, and have it deleted at the end (or in case an exception occurs when processing the data), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804). Using this option, one wouldn't have to prepend a BOM to the data, as described earlier when using Pandas DataFrame.

```py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import csv
import os

@app.get("/4")
def get_csv(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    headers = {"Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="out.csv"'}
    temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, mode='w', encoding='utf-16', newline='')
    try:
        with temp as f:
            keys = data[0].keys()
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=keys, delimiter='\t')
            w.writeheader()
            w.writerows(data)
    except Exception:
        os.remove(temp.name)
        raise HTTPException(detail='There was an error processing the data', status_code=400)

    background_tasks.add_task(os.remove, temp.name)
    return FileResponse(temp.name, headers=headers, media_type='text/csv; charset=utf-16')
```

or, a variant of the above (remember to call `.seek(0)` to reset the cursor back to the start of the file, before reading the contents from it—see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653605/17865804) for more details):

```py
from fastapi import HTTPException
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import csv
import os

@app.get("/5")
def get_csv():
    headers = {"Content-Disposition": 'attachment; filename="out.csv"'}
    temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, mode='w+', encoding='utf-16', newline='')
    try:
        keys = data[0].keys()
        w = csv.DictWriter(temp, fieldnames=keys, delimiter='\t')
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerows(data)
        temp.seek(0)
        return Response(temp.read().encode('utf-16'), headers=headers, media_type='text/csv; charset=utf-16')
    except Exception:
        raise HTTPException(detail='There was an error processing the data', status_code=400)
    finally:
        temp.close()
        os.remove(temp.name)
```

#### Note 1

it should also be noted that if one didn't use any of the options provided above, they could still open the file downloaded using the standard Notepad application and change the encoding to `Unicode` by clicking on "File > Save as > Encoding: Unicode", and then save it. In Notepad++, you could do that by clicking on the "Encoding" tab and selecting `UTF-16 LE BOM`, then save it. In both cases, double-click on the file after channging the encoding should display unicode characters as expected. There is also the option of opening the Excel application first, and then importing the csv file, which would let you specify the encoding (lokk for guidelines online on how to do that). Regardless, using one of the approaches demonstrated earlier, the contents of the csv file would be shown as expected, when double-clicking the file to open it in Excel.

#### Note 2

In every option given above, the endpoints were defined with normal `def`, instead of `async def`, as I/O operations of Pandas DataFrame, Python's built-in `json` and `csv` modules, as well as `NamedTemporaryFile`, are all blocking operations. Thus, depending on the size of data to be written/read, as well as the number of users that might need concurrent access to your API, you might otherwise noticed delays, when you (or some other user) attempted to access the same or a different endpoint, while a request was already being processed. If an endpoint was defined with `async def` and you had to process (read/write) large size data, and didn't `await` for some `async` function inside the endpoint—in order to return control back to the event loop and allow other tasks/requests waiting in the event loop to run—every request to such an endpoint would have to be completely finished (i.e., exit the endpoint), before letting other tasks/requests in the event loop to run.

When, instead, defining an endpoint with normal `def`, FastAPI will run that endpoint in an external `ThreadPool` that is then `await`ed; hence, avoiding blocking the event loop. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details and examples on that subject. That answer also provides solutions, when one needs to define their endpoint with `async def`, as they would have to `await` for some `async` function inside it, as well as, at the same time,
they would have to execute blocking operations inside that endpoint. Such solutions include running blocking opertions in an external threadpool or processpool and `await`ing it. Please have a look at the linked answer above for furhter details. If you would also like using an `async` version of `NamedTemporaryFile`, please take a look at Option 2 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73324461/17865804), which uses `aiofiles`.

If the size of the data you had to process was small, and you didn't expect a large amount of clients/users to use your API at the same time, it would be just fine to define the endpoint with `async def` (even without having blocking operations, such as `json.dumps()`, `Pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()`, etc., run in external threadpool or processpool). It all depends on your needs.